# How to add and display a taxonomy term image in any template? (Taxonomy Images)

Tags: taxonomy

How do I add and display an image for a taxonomy term in any template? I am using the plugin Taxonomy Images but I can find the right code snippet that will display the image in all template files.

I'm trying to do fetch an image for a single term on index.php, archive.php and taxonomy-term.php. Each page contains a loop of posts and I want to display the taxonomy term image for each post filed under a taxonomy term. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use a plugin, then you'll essentially have to write your own which strikes me as counter-productive. I would recommend using a plugin and figuring out how to make it work.

I've used mfields' [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/) to great effect. The way you access the image is certainly a little funky in some situations, but it works. There are some good code snippets in the WordPress.org support forum for that plugin in addition to what is provided on the Plugin page.

Comment: The problem with that plugin is that it wont display the image on index.php

Comment: "It won't display the image on index.php?" It sounds like you haven't found the write code snippet yet. Can you maybe update your question to ask about that specific problem? Like I said, I've had good luck with that plugin, even if it's a little frustrating at times.

Comment: I have updated my question. What snippet do you use?

Comment: That completely depends on what you're trying to do (single term? many terms? terms assigned to a post?). Include the code you're trying to use, a description of EXACTLY what you're trying to do, and any progress you have made (even if it's not what you want yet).

Comment: I'm trying to do fetch an image for a single term on index.php, archive.php and taxonomy.php. Each page contains a loop of posts and I want to display the taxonomy term image for each post filed under a taxonomy term. Is that clearer?